# java.lang.NullpointerException in kettle/status with xml=n

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I am trying to check the status of my jobs through the kettle/status page, however, I am receiving the error below. Using the xml=y parameter, the page displays the status list.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.pentaho.di.www.CarteObjectEntry.compare(CarteObjectEntry.java:67)
    at org.pentaho.di.www.CarteObjectEntry.compareTo(CarteObjectEntry.java:76)
    at org.pentaho.di.www.GetStatusServlet.lambda$doGet$1(GetStatusServlet.java:495)
    at java.util.TimSort.binarySort(TimSort.java:296)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:239)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1512)
    at java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1462)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:175)
    at org.pentaho.di.www.GetStatusServlet.doGet(GetStatusServlet.java:498)
    at org.pentaho.di.www.CarteServlet.doGet(CarteServlet.java:75)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)...
```

I need to view it in HTML format to be able to check the details of the job execution.

Comment: In more detail, I need to display this page:
https://higherlogicdownload.s3.amazonaws.com/HITACHI/MigratedImages/0681J000006Pu9eQAC.png
To be able to see this detail page:
https://higherlogicdownload.s3.amazonaws.com/HITACHI/MigratedImages/0681J000006Pu9jQAC.png
for auditing purposes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is no code, I am simply accessing my server at address "http://localhost:8082/kettle/status" to obtain the list of the latest executions to view the details, and this default page is returning the exception

Answer (score 0):

In order to check the Pentaho Job status, you need to use the `/kettle/jobStatus` REST endpoint and pass the job name as a parameter. The request format will be as follow:

```
http://localhost:8082/kettle/jobStatus/?job=yourJob.kjb
```

This will return the HTML version of the pentaho Job status. Assuming your pentaho job name is `yourJob.kjb` and the carte server is running on `localhost:8082`.

If you want to have an XML version, you can achieve that by adding an xml parameter to the request, as below:

```
http://localhost:8082/kettle/jobStatus/?job=yourJob.kjb&xml=Y
```